# PHP array_map not returning resultant array

Tags: php, array-map

I am trying to replace an array value's spacing with hypen and then recollect back all values of the same array but with hypen in spaces.

INPUT:

```
$gFontsList = array("-1", "Agency FB", "28", "Aharoni Bold", "Bookshelf Symbol", "100", "Bookshelf Symbol", "111", "Browallia New Bol");

function toReplaceSpacing($gFontsListValues, $gFontsListIndex){
   if (gettype($gFontsListValues) === 'string'){
      if(preg_match('/ /',$gFontsListValues)){
        $gFontsListValues = str_replace(' ','-',$gFontsListValues);
        $gFontsChoiceOrder[] = $gFontsListValues;
      }
    } else {
      $gFontsChoiceOrder[] = $gFontsListValues;
    }
}
$gFontsChoiceOrder = array_map('toReplaceSpacing',$gFontsList);
print_r($gFontsChoiceOrder);
```

If I print it's just NULL. I don't know Why I am not getting resultant array?.

Comment: assumed `toReplaceSpacing` returns new `$gFontsListValues`

Comment: I even tried returning `$gFontsChoiceOrder` but no result.

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything. From what i can see all your code is doing is replacing spaces with hyphens, in which case you could just do `$gFontsChoiceOrder = array_map(function($v) { return str_replace(' ', '-', $v); }, $gFontsList);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove that second parameter `$gFontsListIndex` and then just return a value `gFontsListValues`.

```
$gFontsList = array("-1", "Agency FB", "28", "Aharoni Bold", "Bookshelf Symbol", "100", "Bookshelf Symbol", "111", "Browallia New Bol");

function toReplaceSpacing($gFontsListValues){

   $gFontsChoiceOrder = array();

   if (gettype($gFontsListValues) === 'string'){

      if(preg_match('/ /',$gFontsListValues)){

        $gFontsListValues = str_replace(' ','-',$gFontsListValues);
      }
   }

   return $gFontsListValues;
}

$gFontsChoiceOrder = array_map('toReplaceSpacing',$gFontsList);
print_r($gFontsChoiceOrder);
```

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

```
function toReplaceSpacing($gFontsListValues){
   if (gettype($gFontsListValues) === 'string'){
        $gFontsListValues = str_replace(' ','-',$gFontsListValues);
   }
   return $gFontsListValues;
}
```

1. You need to return the new value
2. The callback only takes the value, so only one argument

Also, I don't see any reason to check for a space (especially with a regex) before replacing and it makes the code longer.

As [billyonecan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1087721/billyonecan) points out in the comments, it can be done with an anonymous function, but this version doesn't check for string so can cause issues with arrays, objects, etc:

```
$gFontsChoiceOrder = array_map(function($v) {
                                   return str_replace(' ', '-', $v);
                               }, $gFontsList);
```

For future reference, you can modify the original array with `array_walk()` and a reference:

```
function toReplaceSpacing(&$gFontsListValues){
   if (gettype($gFontsListValues) === 'string'){
        $gFontsListValues = str_replace(' ','-',$gFontsListValues);
   }
}
array_walk($gFontsList, 'toReplaceSpacing');
```